# Selenium clicked on button but the button didnt actually got clicked

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, testng, ui-automation

I am trying to click on a button in a webpage
basically its a Submit button created normal xpath by text "`//*[text()='Submit']`"
I noticed the button color gets little light like its been actually mouse hovered on but it didn't get clicked
I tried many many things

```
action class to click

Javascript executor to click

Javascript executor to scrollintoview then click
```

many many things

but it just do hover like thing but the button doesn't get click and still my test case shows passed

below is the html for same

[link to the html page DOM screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3fu5.png)

screenshot to console below

[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhtO4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since You have mentioned that you've been trying with Actions, JS and none of them worked. Did you try with `explicit waits` ?

Are you sure `//*[text()='Submit']` this has unique entry in HTML DOM ?

if **yes**, then you can give a try with `explicit waits` :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[text()='Submit']"))).click();
```

Comment: moreover what happens is that whatever i've filled in the form which i am trying to submit that values which i filled are now wiping off when i try to click on submit but still it didnt get submitted

Comment: no error stack trace 
the test case is showing passed
but it didnt clicked

Comment: Cruisepandey can u please share ur skype id or something i want to connect with u and really get this thing worked

Comment: It's highly unlikely, if explicit waits do not work they throw Timeout exception. Can you share your console screenshot, you can append that into your question post

Comment: attached screenshot of console

Comment: Can you share page URL ?

Comment: http://wallethub.com/profile/test_insurance_company/

u have to create account there and post a review

Comment: Oops! This IP address has been blocked due to too many requests. To unblock, please send your IP address via email to help@wallethub.com. I got this

Comment: abhishek can u please connect me on  my gmail : fernandolinr@gmail.com 
lets chat there i will show u exactly

Comment: you have to use US IP VPn